# Creating multiple chat windows using Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am doing a project and need to create a chat client. I have created the friend list and on double click on friend in the list a new chat window should be displayed. The chat window i want to design has a `Jtextpane`(for the conversation), Jtextarea(user input) and a send button. I have used GUI in netbeans to create the new window.

I make the chatwindow visible on clicking the friend from the friend list but i am not sure how i will instantiate another window which i click on another friend from my friend list.

Comment: create a new instance of your window for every friend, passing the friend as a parameter?

Comment: yes. New instance of the chatwindow for every friend.

Comment: Create a chat window for each friend every time if it is not created. For this chat window, you can pass friend name/ id as parameter. For conference chat, you can have multiple friend names as parateters (some list object).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)